# Is the JDK 1.6 the development kit for Java 6?

Tags: java, java-6

I have the following doubt. For a Spring training course they say to me that I have to prepare my environment installing the JDK 1.6 on Windows.

So what it means? That I have to install the JDK related to Java 6? Is the JDK 1.6 the development kit for the Java 6?

Is this one the correct link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html ?

Is it not so old?

Tnx

Comment: Find a more recent tutorial. Java is at version (1.)8.

Comment: Java 6 and JDK 1.6 are indeed the same thing. But yes, indeed, it's really old. The latest Spring versions supports Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awnser is yes, 1.6 relates to Java 6. The newest version is Java 8 or 1.8. 
You probably don't need to have Java 6 jdk to have your tutorial work, I would use at least Java 7.